# How to make a conditional copy in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I am trying to make a cell, on a separate sheet, and copy it from another sheet, if a cell in that row is a specific word.

**Sheet 1**

| Row# | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1: | Data needed1 | No |
| Row 2: | Data needed2 | Yes |

**Sheet 2**

| Row# | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| Row 1: | Data needed2 |
| Row 2: | Empty |

Basicaly I need a =Sheet1!a1 IF Sheet1!b1=yes

I found a conditional formatting thing on google help but it is only able to change cells conditionally in reference to data on that specific sheet. At least that's what I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet1!B:B="Yes")
```